# How can I get input value more than one from console nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I want to get input values from the console. Although I am getting one input values, the console doesn't return more than one input value.

When I as soon as entering the '2' number, the code terminates.

Like below,

#### my input:

```
2
```

#### my output:

```
Dates:  undefined
Dates:  undefined
```

But, I want to enter the input value twice.

Like below,

#### input:

```
2
10/11/2009
11/10/2010
```

#### output:

```
Dates:  Sunday
Dates:  Wednesday
```

### Script:

```
'use strict'

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: console.log
})

// The days of the week are: "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
function getDayName(dateString) {
    let dayName;
    // Write your code here

    var day_names = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    var date = new Date(dateString)

    dayName = day_names[date.getDay()];


    return dayName;
}

rl.on('line', input => {

    const d = input.trim().split('')
    for (let i = 0; i < d; i++) {

        const a = input.trim().split('\n').map(string => {
            return string.trim();
        });

        console.log('Dates: ', getDayName(a));
    }

    rl.close();

});
```

Comment: You could save the lines in an array that is declared outside the `rl.on('line')` callback.

Comment: And `input.trim().split('')` returns an array of all characters you entered in the last line. Comparing a number to an array is dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the readline library does, this works for me:

```
const process = require('process');

process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

let results = [];

process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
    let chunk;
    while ((chunk = process.stdin.read()) !== null) {
        results.push(getDayName(chunk));
        // 2 = amount of lines you want to read
        if (results.length === 2) {
            for (let i = 0; i < results.length ;i++) {
                console.log("Dates: " + results[i]);
            }
            //if you do not do a break this will go on forever until you press ctrl + c
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

I hope I helped

Comment: Despite dates don't exactly match, your solution has helped my problem. Thanks.